# Parsing complex (for me!) Xml from web service

Tags: xml, web-services, asp-classic

i'm calling a web service receiving a XML output, but i'm not able to parse it to extract data.

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <wsextOutput>
- <header>
   <webServiceName>BASKET</webServiceName> 
   <callingId>CLST01</callingId> 
   <assignedId>3432876</assignedId> 
  </header>
- <response>
- <complexAttribute name="product">
- <values>
  <value name="productCode">123457</value> 
  <value name="time0">F</value> 
  <value name="availability0">1</value> 
  <value name="time1">36h</value> 
  <value name="availability1">9</value> 
  </values>
  </complexAttribute>
- <complexAttribute name="product">
- <values>
  <value name="productCode">00048</value> 
  <value name="time0">F</value> 
  <value name="availability0">0</value> 
  <value name="time1">16h</value> 
  <value name="availability1">10</value> 
  </values>
  </complexAttribute>
  </response>
  </wsextOutput>
```

I tried in this way:

```
Dim disp_rh
disp_rh=objRequest.ResponseXML
Set xmlResponse = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument.4.0")
xmlResponse.LoadXML(disp_rh)
Dim pcode
pcode=xmlResponse.selectSingleNode"/wsextOutput/response/complexAttribute/values/productCode").text
Response.write(Server.HTMLEncode("Codice prodotto="&pcode&""))
```

With this code i've a Run-time Error VBScript '800a01b6' at the row disp_rh=objRequest.ResponseXML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code missing opening bracket, and the xpath query isn't correct at the last bit :

```
/wsextOutput/response/complexAttribute/values/value[@name='productCode']
                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                              notice changes here
```

The modified part of the xpath means get `<value>` elements having `name` attribute equals `"productCode"`.